# Input Data into Neo4j using jdbc template form Mysql

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, jdbctemplate

I have to **input** some **data** and make **relationships** in **neo4j**, I am trying doing it by **jdbctemplate (java spring)**. I have created the **POJO's** and the **DAO** class,  I have used jdbc template resultset for storing the query data into lists now I am struck how to continue this. Please suggest me a suitable way to do this, with an example.I am basically struck in **inputting** data into **neo4j** from the result sets or **lists** .
Thanks In advance

Comment: not enough information

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Cypher statements with placeholders for numeric variables: `{1}` or `$1` and then set positional parameters for prepared statements.

JDBC Templates with Prepared Statements are explained here:
https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-jdbc-tutorial-1.html

Comment: Does it also support Named Parameters?.